# HTTP GET to amazon aws from jquery or XMLHttpRequest fails with Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: jquery, amazon-web-services, xmlhttprequest, amazon-dynamodb

Having some bad luck with getting amazon AWS security token from jQuery or XMLHttpRequest. When I send a HTTP GET from jQuery or XmlHttpRequest, I get "Origin http:// MY_IP is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.", but if I paste the same URL in my browser, it all goes fine.

My code:

```
var url_ = "https://sts.amazonaws.com/?Action=GetSessionToken" +
            "&DurationSeconds=3600" +
            "&AWSAccessKeyId=" + AccessKeyId +
            "&Version=2011-06-15" +
            "&Timestamp=" + encode(timestamp) +
            "&Signature=" + encode(hash) +
            "&SignatureVersion=2&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256";
$.get(url_, function(data) {
alert("response: "+data);
});
```

**My Headers:**

Response Headers
Accept-Ranges   bytes
Age 198
Connection  Keep-Alive
Content-Length  3739
Content-Type    text/html
Date    Mon, 25 Jun 2012 17:48:20 GMT
Etag    "48c4862-e9b-4c34f76b13400"
Last-Modified   Mon, 25 Jun 2012 17:39:28 GMT
Proxy-Connection    Keep-Alive
Server  Apache/2.2.21 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/0.9.8r DAV/2 PHP/5.3.10 with Suhosin-Patch

Request Headers
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
DNT 1
Host    **MY_IP**
If-Modified-Since   Mon, 25 Jun 2012 17:13:16 GMT
If-None-Match   "48c127c-ea2-4c34f18fe6300"
Proxy-Connection    keep-alive
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0

**Browser headers (if used URL in browser)**

Response Headers
Content-Length  808
Content-Type    text/xml
Date    Mon, 25 Jun 2012 17:31:54 GMT
x-amzn-RequestId    a854ff13-beeb-11e1-b3ac-0147da731d96

Request Headers
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Connection  keep-alive
DNT 1
Host    **sts.amazonaws.com**
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0

I tried some code from http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/ , but no luck

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You asked that question a while ago, you might already have found your answer, but in case someone else is looking for the answer to this question, here it is:

Access-Control-Allow-Origin is a security feature of XMLHttpRequest when doing a request that is outside of the domain of the web page running the javascript.

For example, a web page http://foo.com/index.html is doing a XMLHttpRequest request for http://bar.com/query?a=b, the server at bar.com must put Access-Control-Allow-Origin in the response headers to specify that cross domain requests are permitted.

Amazon AWS, unfortunately, does not provide Access-Control-Allow-Origin in the response headers, so that means that you can't access it using this technique.

The only technique that works with AWS is using flash to proxy the XMLHttpRequest, but this only works on devices that have flash installed (no iphone or ipads).

Comment: Do you happen to have a reference that explains how to use flash as a CORS proxy?

Comment: I suggest you use a library that does that for you, I personally use YUI: http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/io/