# Amazon S3 CORS Configuration XMLHttpRequest GET

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, cors, xmlhttprequest

I'm hosting a static website via Amazon S3 and I have some Javascript on there that will make a call to another domain and parse the XML, JSON, or whatever that it gets.

I followed the many posts on stackoverflow and various blog posts it linked to that claimed to get it working but even after following very closely I could never replicate the results.

```
 <CORSRule>
   <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
   <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
 </CORSRule>
```

I even tried adding with and without the following to the rule,

```
 <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
```

The following link allows you to test if CORS is enabled by sending XMLHttpRequests and it says it is not valid so CORS is not set up or recognized properly.

http://client.cors-api.appspot.com/client/

A possible lead is what is suggested in Amazon S3 documentation here,

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGETcors.html

that says we need to set the "s3:GetCORSConfiguration" permission, which I did via a line like...

"Action": ["s3:GetObject", "s3:GetCORSConfiguration"],

in the "edit bucket policy" section from the AWS control panel but it gives an error and cannot save because it doesn't recognize this action?

A potentially similar post on stackexchange here,

[HTTP GET to amazon aws from jquery or XMLHttpRequest fails with Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11201738/http-get-to-amazon-aws-from-jquery-or-xmlhttprequest-fails-with-origin-is-not-al)

seems to suggest that if I have a website hosted on S3 that it can not configure it to make XMLHttpRequests that are GET to a 3rd party resource?

I feel like I'm going in circles. Does anyone have any leads/advice?

Answer (score 1):

You have to expose the access control headers. Try this:

```
<CORSRule>
  <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
  <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
  <ExposeHeader>Access-Control-Allow-Origin</ExposeHeader>
  <ExposeHeader>Access-Control-Allow-Methods</ExposeHeader>
</CORSRule>
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be some relation here to the example we just worked through on our apps which was related to the https which was a hardcoded configuration on some of our clients machines. I don't know exactly what that means but it might be a place to check.

instead of http:// try https://

[XMLHttpRequest to Amazon S3 fails only on some computers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27386108/xmlhttprequest-to-amazon-s3-fails-only-on-some-computers/27386441#27386441)

Answer (score -1):

I think you are confused or I misread your question.

You enable CORS on your site so other sites can make requests to your page.

Enabling CORS on your S3 site will allow example.com to talk to your S3 page. It does not allow your site to talk to example.com.

In order for you to make requests to other domains, they have to enable the privileges. You can not magically turn it on for their domains. It is like saying that you give permission to yourself to walk into the whitehouse and use the president's bathroom. When you hop the fence, the secret service will deny that request with force.

Comment: haha, thanks for the reply, I could be mistaken...but I'm so confused that I'm just not sure...

$.getJSON("https://api.github.com/users/githubuser/events")

Works fine on a test server on say my desktop (or even from my other websites if I make it through the Chrome developer console) but when I try to make the same call after I've uploaded that website to Amazon S3 then it does not work because I get the XMLHttpRequests error.

Logically this suggests to me that it has something to do with my configuration on the Amazon S3 bucket since it did work in a test environment and certain websites?